# Why Firebase Cloud messages notification is not receiving on my other iOS Devices?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated FCM in my iOS Project, I've uploaded APNs key and configure all the required pods in order to achieve FCM, and it looks fine the notification is been receiving on my physical iOS Device iPhone 6s.
But if I run my project on my other iOS Device FCM notification will not receive on that device but it will receive a notification on my first device (iPhone 6s) what is this?

I also search and got some answers that add a Provisional profile for all of your test devices and I did but it's not working, all FCM Notification is received on my first device (iPhone 6s) but not any other device.

what do I do? do I upload a production certificate rather than upload APNs key or something else?

Comment: Check the device notification permission in device settings -> your App-> Notifications. may this will cause.

Comment: try uninstalling the app form that device and install it again. And as @Golukumar said check settings as well